# Как и чем заменить StdDraw.show(int)

Tags: java

```
public static void drawGus(double[][] arr) {    
    StdDraw.clear();    
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        StdDraw.filledCircle( arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2]);    
    StdDraw.show(2000);//вот тут show перечеркивается  
}
```

Comment: узнала ,что когда перечеркивается это значит, что данный метод устарел... а вот на что заменить, не знаю

Comment: можно пожалуйста поподробнее объяснить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если метод устарел - это означает, что вы не должны его больше использовать, поскольку он был заменен чем-то более лучшим и, вероятно, будет удален в будущем. В таких случаях вам предлагается использовать методы `enableDoubleBuffering()`, `show()` (без аргумента) и `pause(int t)` как указано [здесь](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html#show-int-), поскольку вы,  весьма вероятно, используете стандартную [библиотеку](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) Принстонского университета

В таких случаях лучше сразу обращаться к документации, - там вы найдете, чем рекомендуется заместить соответствующие устаревшие методы.

Comment: спасибо большое!